# Why does not Bhabha scattering contain u-channel diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams

$e^+e^-\rightarrow e^+e^-$ is called Bhabha scattering. Let us only consider the tree level Feynman diagrams of this process. Apparantly, there are s-channel and t-channel diagrams as shown in the linked wiki page [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering). But there should also be a u-channel diagram obtained by modifying the "Scattering" diagram:

[image]

Sorry for bad hand drawing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You only need to include $u$ and $t$ channels when the final particles are indistinguishable (classically thinking, you don't know which blip in your detector came from which initial particle).  Since $e^-$ and $e^+$ are distinguishable, you will always know which one is which and only $t$ channel contributes to the scattering amplitude.

Comment: So it means that if we consider the process $e^+ e^- \to e^- e^+$, then we should add $u$-channel rather than $t$-channel. Right?

Comment: @ChoMedit The is no physical difference between $e^+ e^- \to e^+ e^-$ and $e^+ e^- \to e^- e^+$. In these cases the difference between the $t$ and $u$ channels is just which final particle is labeled "$+$" and which is labelled "$-$".  $u$-channel and $t$-channel would both contribute to $e^+ e^- \to \gamma \gamma$, where the final state particles are indistinguishable.

Comment: Then, is it okay to evaluate with u-channel instead of t-channel?

Comment: @ChoMedit You'll have to be more specific, what are you trying to do?  By convention, $t$ is calculated from the difference of the momenta of the most similar particles in the initial and final states, for Bhabha e.g. $t = (p(e^-)_{in} - p(e^-)_{out})^2$, whereas $u$ uses the dissimilar particles: $u = (p(e^-)_{in} - p(e^+)_{out})^2$. The Bhabha scattering amplitude has contributions from both $s$ and $t$-channel diagrams, but not $u$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot the amplitude.